# Mac Address - C++ - Platform independent

Tags: c++, network-programming

I am trying to generate the Mac address using C++ program. I have found few examples over net, but they are specific to Operating system. Is there any possibility to generate the Mac Id using platform independent code.
Please guide.

Regards,
Srikanth

Comment: *Generate* or *obtain* the addresses of network adapters currently installed in the machine?

Answer (score 3):

This is outside the purview of standard C++, so no, strictly speaking there isn't a platform independent way of doing it. Your best bet is to find a library that wraps up the OS-specific functionality for all the platforms you care about, or #ifdef it yourself.

This is assuming you mean you need to *obtain* the MAC address of a real network device. If you just need to fake something that looks like any old MAC address, other answers here apply.

Answer (score 1):

A MAC address is just a 48 bit number. The easiest way to generate one is to take a 32-bit and a 16-bit random number and put them together. Note: This can of course generate invalid MAC addresses, or addresses that are already in use on your network.

Comment: I got the macid using the program http://wxwidgets.info/cross-platform-way-of-obtaining-mac-address-of-your-machine/ with minor modifications. But when compiling with g++ under windows it is unable to link the uuid library and throwing undefined reference to `_UuidCreate@4'. Is there a way I get macid under windows using g++ (cygwin or mingw environmant). Thank you